# React invalid Hook Call Warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dependencies, frontend

Running code using React I got "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component."

Here's the code

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles'

    const useStyles = makeStyles({
     footer_mobile: {
    backgroundColor: '#080d26',
    padding: '20px',
  },
  typo: {
    color: 'white',
    marginRight: '32px',
    '&:hover': {
      textDecoration: 'none',
      color: 'white',
      cursor: 'pointer',
    },
  },
  div: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  icon: {
    marginRight: '4px',
    color: 'white',
    '&:hover': {
      cursor: 'pointer',
      color: 'white',
    },
  },
  iconContainer: {
    marginRight: '32px',
  },
  footer: {
    backgroundColor: '#080d26',
  },
    })


export default function Footer() {
  const classes = useStyles() //the line where error happened
...
```

Among the 3 possible causes:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I eliminated 2, and eliminated 1 because running npm ls react-dom I got

```
├─┬ @mui/material@5.2.7
│ ├─┬ @mui/base@5.0.0-alpha.63
│ │ └── react-dom@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├── react-dom@17.0.2 deduped
│ └─┬ react-transition-group@4.4.2
│   └── react-dom@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ next@12.0.7
│ ├─┬ @next/react-dev-overlay@12.0.7
│ │ └── react-dom@17.0.2 deduped
│ └── react-dom@17.0.2 deduped
├── react-dom@17.0.2
└─┬ react-router-dom@6.2.1
  └── react-dom@17.0.2 deduped
```

so my react-dom is not < 16.8.0.

I'm not sure about 3 because I don't understand my dependency tree. Do I have more than 1 react? Here's what I got from npm ls react

```
├─┬ @emotion/react@11.7.1
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ @emotion/styled@11.6.0
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ @mui/icons-material@5.2.5
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ @mui/material@5.2.7
│ ├─┬ @mui/base@5.0.0-alpha.63
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ @mui/system@5.2.6
│ │ ├─┬ @mui/styled-engine@5.2.6
│ │ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ @mui/utils@5.2.3
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-transition-group@4.4.2
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ @mui/styles@5.2.3
│ ├─┬ @mui/private-theming@5.2.3
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ next@12.0.7
│ ├─┬ @next/react-dev-overlay@12.0.7
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ styled-jsx@5.0.0-beta.3
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ └─┬ use-subscription@1.5.1
│   └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-dom@17.0.2
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-router-dom@6.2.1
│ ├─┬ react-router@6.2.1
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-split@2.0.14
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
└── react@17.0.2
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the code for `makeStyles` please?

Comment: @larz Just did! Didn't include it bc it's not my code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: this might sound a little stupid, but are the brackets arranged correctly? react could throw nonsensical error in those times

Comment: by any chance the file is being called as `js` instead of `jsx` ?

Comment: I was looking for how you're exporting `makeStyles`.

Comment: @tsamridh86 neither is the problem, but thanks!

Comment: @larz I didn't export makeStyles directly. The only thing I export in this file is footer in which I called makeStyles and assigned it to class